# unable to send Broadcast from activity :android

Tags: android

hi friends i am unable to send Broadcast from one activity to other activity pls see my code below and help:

```
      public class SendBroadcast extends Activity {
  public static String BROADCAST_ACTION =  "com.unitedcoders.android.broadcasttest.SHOWTOAST";

/*     }
    });
}



   public void sendBroadcast(){

    Intent broadcast = new Intent("com.unitedcoders.android.broadcasttest.SHOWTOAST");
    this.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
    //startActivity(broadcast);



}
```

}

Receiving side code:

```
    public class ToastDisplay extends Activity {

private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("!!!!!!!InchooTutorial@@@@@@@$$$$","%%%%%%% msg_for_me");
```

ent
              //  String msg_for_me = intent.getStringExtra("some_msg");
                //log our message value
                Log.i("!!!!!!!InchooTutorial@@@@@@@$$$$","%%%%%%% msg_for_me");

```
        }
    };
    //registering our receiver
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
}

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    //unregister our receiver
    this.unregisterReceiver(this.mReceiver);
}

}
```

Manifest.xml is:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unitedcoders.android.broadcasttest"
    android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".SendBroadcast"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
           <intent-filter>
          nitedcoders.android.broadcasttest.SHOWTOAST" />
   </application>     </manifest>
```

Comment: Have you added the reciever to the manifest?

Comment: pls refer to also my manifest file..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the other activity is not running when u send broadcast u wont receive it. 
If u want to receive broadcasts even when the activity is not running . Declare it in xml .

Here is the code for you. I hope this is what you want.

```
package com.pdd.Receiver;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ReceiverActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i =new Intent("com.pdd.receiver.myaction");
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}
```

Receiver Class

```
package com.pdd.Receiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Intent i=new Intent(MyReceiver.class,Second.class);
        Intent i=new Intent(arg0,Second.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        arg0.startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

Second Activity to display Toast

```
package com.pdd.Receiver;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Second extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is second activity", 5000).show();
    }
}
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pdd.Receiver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <receiver android:name="com.pdd.Receiver.MyReceiver">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="com.pdd.receiver.myaction"></action>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".ReceiverActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Second"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: yours means in manifest.xml? pls refer to my Manifestfile.xml and if u can do modification on it..

Comment: should i start Activity inside on my SendBroadcast() method?

Comment: here is an example                                          <receiver android:name="com.pdd.vayu.ServiceStarter">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
             </intent-filter>
         </receiver>

Comment: call startActivity in onreceive of broadcast receiver !!

Comment: hey pratik ...i am not extending service for sending Broadcast to other activity..pls first read my question..

Comment: It was just an example to show how to declare a receiver in manifest. It had nothing to do with service..

Answer (score 1):

If your SendBroadcast activity is created the broadcast will be send.

Then you start the second activity called ToastDisplay and in the onResume you register the BroadcastReceiver. But this is to late, the broadcast was already send, it will not stay in the system!

Try sending a stickybroadcast like:

```
sendStickyBroadcast(Intent)
```

Or declare the broadcastreceiver in the manifest but then you need to create a seperate class that extends the BroadcastReceiver class, this cannot be inherreted.

Comment: i appreciating urs effort and nice understanding but sendStickyBroadcast(Intent) also not working.. :(

Comment: public void sendBroadcast(){

        Intent broadcast = new Intent("com.unitedcoders.android.broadcasttest.SHOWTOAST");
        this.sendStickyBroadcast(broadcast);
     
     
  
    }